# Vba coding for Excel - remove rows that don't match two criteria

Tags: excel

This is my first post so I hope this is the correct forum

I am using Excel 2003 and have the following code
This code looks at column "F" and deletes all the rows that do not match criteria "2220"

This works fine but I am trying to modify this so I can match "2220" and also "er4cc"

Any help would be great

```
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 2 Step -1
If InStr(1, Range("F" & i).Value, "2220") = 0 Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 2 Step -1
If InStr(1, Range("F" & i).Value, "2220") = 0 _ 
  Or InStr(1, Range("F" & i).Value, "er4cc") Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
```

Try that out?

The "_" is a linebreak, it just makes the line easier to read.

edit - you said 'match "2220" and also "er4cc"' , I interpreted that as 'delete if it has 2220 OR er4cc' , if you meant 2220 AND er4cc then just replace the Or with And -

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working as I would like

I want to delete all the rows that do not match

"2220"

And all the rows that do not match

"er4cc"

At the moment this code keeps the rows that match "2220" but deletes the rows that match "er4cc"

Comment: Ok, then try -- If InStr(1, Range("F" & i).Value, "2220")
  Or InStr(1, Range("F" & i).Value, "er4cc") Then --